# Мобильный интернет (передача данных)

Tags: android, android-sdk

Как проверить включена ли на аппарате передача данных? Сразу нужно уточнить, что меня не интересует наличие интренета, нужен ответ: вкл/выкл

Answer (score 1):

> Как проверить включена ли на аппарате передача данных?

Например, [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32239785):

```
boolean mobileYN = false;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    mobileYN = Settings.Global.getInt(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), "mobile_data", 1) == 1;
}
else {
    mobileYN = Settings.Secure.getInt(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), "mobile_data", 1) == 1;
}
```

Comment: работает не корректно

Comment: @Jorik, На какой версии андроида?

Comment: 4.4.2. Вроде 19 API.

Comment: @Jorik, Только что проверил на 4.4.2 – работает.

Comment: У меня включены GPS и WiFi, но моб. интернет выключен - выдает true

Answer (score 1):

Там же есть правильный ответ:

```
boolean mobileDataEnabled = false; // Assume disabled
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
try {
    Class cmClass = Class.forName(cm.getClass().getName());
    Method method = cmClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
    method.setAccessible(true); // Make the method callable
    // get the setting for "mobile data"
    mobileDataEnabled = (Boolean)method.invoke(cm);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Some problem accessible private API
    // TODO do whatever error handling you want here
}
```